# How can I see the communication of the RestKit network (JSON string)?

Tags: restkit

I wish to see the JSON input/output of the iPhone. How can I do that?

Do I need to set use `NSLog()` (and where)? Or, set the RestKit logging level (to what)?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try placing this `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);` in your AppDelegate

Comment: RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) - Debugging Proxy

Comment: Charles is by far the best solution. The logging output of RestKit is so heavy on performance, that except for trivial examples it isn't practical. Also it still doesn't seem to clearly show POSTing bodies.