# How can I print the body sent by Restkit (IOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, restkit

I'm sendind an object through RKObjectManager:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:myObject delegate:delegate];
```

The mapping and route is already configured and it works successfully. It sends a json and the server receive the request, but I have a question. On IOS side, how can I print the json sent to the server.

Comment: You probably want to enable logging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664892/how-can-i-see-the-communication-of-the-restkit-networkjson-string/7666125#7666125

Comment: Thank you, that's what I'm looking for. Write as an answer for upvote.

Comment: feel free to vote for the original answer, there's no point to duplicate it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Put the following in your app delegate:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace); 
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
```